# How much lawn does two pounds of turf seed cover?

Tags: lawn

We purchased a two-pound [bag](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07J5H12CH) of clover lawn seed. However, the Amazon page and the bag didn't say how much lawn that's supposed to cover.

How many square feet should we use it over?

Answer (score 1):

Clover seeds are *small*. The recommended rate for overseeding agricultural grass land with red clover is about 10 kg/ha.

Converting to USA units, your 2 pound bag is enough for about 1100 square yards, or a quarter of an acre.

Don't sow too early in spring. Germination will be poor if the soil temperature is too cold.

Because of the small seed, you might find it easier to mix the seed with horticultural sand (not builder's sand!!) to make it easier to sow it evenly.

Comment: When is too early? I'm in Minnesota.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea when is too early in Minnesota. I'm in the UK. The soil temperature should be at least 10C (50F). Looking at the Wikipedia page on Minnesota climate, I would guess wait until mid May or early June.

Comment: How do you measure soil temperature? Peak, trough, average?